# How to change only one paramater of a 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays

I created a 2-dimensional array. I need to change the length of for example the first row:

```
{ x, y, z, a} // trying to change the length of only this row

{ b, c, d, e}
{ f, g}{ h, i}
```

I wanted to use: `array1[,] = new int[4, 4, 2, 2];`
but that always has to change the entire list, not only one of the lists.

Please suggest the simplest solution as Im not a very experienced programmer.

I tried:

```
array1[,] = new int[4, 4, 2, 2];
```

Comment: You are probably looking for [jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays).

Comment: As far as I know you cannot change the length of an array runtime, after initialized it

Comment: `array1[,] = new int[4, 4, 2, 2];` will always create a new instance and hence change the entire array. As you're using C# have you thought about using an Enumerable type such as List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a true two-dimensional array, like in your attempt, all rows have the same length. If you use an array of arrays, however, you are free to change any of the rows against a different array.

This is called a "[jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)".

(You still cannot change the length of any existing array, you are always replacing them. You would have to copy the elements from the old one over to the new one if desired.)

Here is a small demonstration program. Note how each row must be initialized with a `new` expression. The nested initializers (`{{1,2}, {1,2,3}}`) you can use for true 2-dimensional arrays don't work here.

```
using System;

namespace jagged_array
{
    class Program
    {
        static void printJaggedArr(int[][] ja)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{");
            foreach (var outer in ja)
            {
                Console.Write("\t{ ");
                foreach (var inner in outer)
                {
                    Console.Write(inner + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("}");

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] jaggedArr 
                = new int[][] 
                    {   new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 
                        new int[] { 4, 5 }, 
                        new int[] { 6 } 
                    };
            printJaggedArr(jaggedArr);

            // replace the first of the "inner" arrays.
            // if you want to keep the old values in the first elements
            // you can use 
            jaggedArr[0] = new int[] { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27 };
            Console.WriteLine("After changing first 'row' (that is, the first array):");
            printJaggedArr(jaggedArr);
        }
    }
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
{
        { 1 2 3 }
        { 4 5 }
        { 6 }
}
After changing first 'row' (that is, the first array):
{
        { 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 }
        { 4 5 }
        { 6 }
}
```

Comment: I think u're really close to what I meant but I only want to set the size of the inner array, not set each element.

Comment: You mean, you want to *extend* the array. That, unfortunately, does not work.

Comment: Anyways I guess I can just do jaggedArr[0] = new int[newSize];

Comment: tysm for tthe help :)

Comment: @winzar_ Yes, of course. The initialization was only a shortcut. Btw, take a look at [Array.Copy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-6.0) and [Array.CopyTo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copyto?view=net-6.0) for copying over elements from the old row.

Comment: Would this code here erase the rest of the arrays? Or am I fine using it. jaggedArr[0] = new int[newSize];

Comment: It would just replace the first row (that is, it would be fine). It does what I do in my program after the "replace the first of the "inner" arrays." comment, except that all ints are zero if you don't specify explicit initialization values.